# Casting of List<Entity1> to another List<Entity2>

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, casting

I would like to perform a cast of something like this:

```
// Entity Data and Entity A_Data has exactly the same properties: sName and sZip.
List<Data> ListData = new List<Data>();
List<A_Data> ListA_Data = (A_Data)ListData.FindAll(item => item.sName.StartsWith("A"));
```

VS2010 keeps telling me that I cannot make this cast.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless a class is explicitly declared to derive from another cast, you cannot cast between them. Even if they have the same properties or fields.

```
class Data  { public string Name { get; set; } public string Zip { get; set; } }
class AData { public string Name { get; set; } public string Zip { get; set; } }

Data  data  = new Data { Name = "Foo", Zip = "Bar" };
AData adata = (AData)data;  // doesn't work
```

You need a converter method in this case:

```
AData ToAData(Data data)
{
    return new AData { Name = data.Name, Zip = data.Zip };
}
```

Not sure if there's anything in EF4 that helps with this.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Cast<T>` extension method:

```
List<A_Data> ListA_Data = ListData.FindAll(item => item.sName.StartsWith("A")).Cast<A_Data>().ToList();
```

It doesn't work the way you have it now because you're trying to cast an `IQueryable<Data>` to an `A_Data`.

Comment: Hi Thank you, it makes sense however when I tried it still didn't work :S

I even tried

    List<A_Data> ListA_Data = ListData.Cast<A_Data>.ToList();

I get a 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollectionExtension.Cast<TResult>(System.DataEnumerableRowCollection' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context.  Any other ideas?

Comment: It should be `.Cast<A_Data>()`. (Parentheses - it's a method.)